# Constructive factorisation of null-homology map through acyclic complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $f: C \rightarrow D$ be a maps of chain complexes on an idempotent complete additive category with all kernel or cokernel (or chain complexes on abelian category).

If $f$ induces a null map in homology. By using the derivaded category, there exist a zig-zag
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X' @>f'>>W @> >> Y' \\
@V \sim V V && @AA \sim A \\
X @>>f>Y @= Y
\end{CD}$$
where $W$ is acyclic and $X' \rightarrow X$ and $Y \rightarrow Y'$ are quasi-isomomorphisms.

So here is my question :

Is there a way to construct explicitly $X'$, $W$ and $Y'$ by using only $X$, $Y$, the boundaries and cycles of these complexes ?

Comment: Are you sure that a map that's zero on homology factors through the zero complex (up to homotopy)? Unless I'm mistaken this is equivalent to Freyd's generating hypothesis for your derived category and that's true only under [regularity assumptions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404906000223).

Comment: As @Denis says, it's not true, even for complexes of abelian groups. If it were true then $f$ would be zero in the derived category, but there are usually plenty of nonzero maps in a derived category that induce the null map on homology.

Comment: I think you're right.
Is it the same for endomorphism (ie. X=Y ) ?

Comment: @MoreauT Yup,  e.g. for $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2 [1]$ and the map induced by the extension $\mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z/2[1]$